# Flash crash after matrix rotation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, matrix

In my Flash program I have a step where I want to rotate a displayObject around the center of its container.
As some of you may know, Flash has a default center point for rotation which is the top left corner, and doesn't fit for my case.
To achieve my specific rotation, I do 3 successive transformations using matrices, like this:

```
public function rotateAroundCenter(object:DisplayObject, container:DisplayObject, angleDegrees:Number):void {               
    var matrix:Matrix = object.transform.matrix;
    var rect:Rectangle = object.getBounds(container);

    matrix.translate(-(rect.left + (rect.width / 2)), -(rect.top + (rect.height / 2)));
    matrix.rotate((angleDegrees / 180) * Math.PI);
    matrix.translate(rect.left + (rect.width / 2), rect.top + (rect.height  / 2));
    object.transform.matrix = matrix; 
}
```

This bit of code does the trick and I can rotate displayObjects around their container center like I want to.

**Problem:**  For some of these objects (couldn't find a discriminating factor between those who work and those who don't), any time I try to apply a ***180 degrees rotation*** to put them upside down using previous bit of code, Flash unloads the SWF, which seems very much like a crash to me. I only get this crash for some of these objects, but if they crash once they crash anytime I apply a 180 degrees rotation using my function.

I suspect a memory leak, but then, if 90 or 270 degrees rotations work, why would this specific case make my whole program crash?

Any clues about this issue will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `Flash unloads the SWF`? What happens exactly?

Comment: In Flash Builder debug console, I get a message saying the SWF has been unloaded, and my application opened in the browser stops right at this moment: can't interact with it anymore.

Comment: "I only get this crash for some of these objects ...", could give us more details about your objects ? And did you tried a debug version of flash player on your browser to get the fired error, if there is one, and I think that there is an error that's why your swf is not responding ?

Comment: I didn't give details regarding the nature of my objects because they are instances of a custom IIPImage viewer, so this is very specific. I use these viewers to display JPEG 2000 images I load from a server. In present case, I put these viewers in containers, and rotate the container itself as explained in the question. I'm using a Flash debug version as said, and I can add that try/catch combo doesn't tell me anything about the crash and doesn't prevent it either...

Comment: can you list some values of rect please? are there any objects which are: 1) very large, 2) zero width/height, or 3) originating in negative coordinate space?

Comment: Here is an example of rect variable I'm using (in a case which results in a crash) just before the first matrix.translate operation: bottom 18000 / height 18000 / left 0 / right 24000 / top 0 / width 24000 / x 0 / y 0